# Getting last condition of if statement to execute if first two conditions return true

Tags: jquery, signalr

How would I get the last part of my if statement to execute if the first two conditions return true:

Here is my code:

```
// main chat code

$(function () {

    var IWannaChat = $.connection.myChatHub;

    IWannaChat.client.addMessage = function (message) {
        $('#listMessages').append('<li>' + message + '</li>');
    };

    $("#sendMessage").click(function () {
        $('#ideaTitle,#ideaBody').each(function () {
            if ($.trim($(this).val()).length === 0) {
                alert('empty');
                return false;
            }
            else if ($.trim($(this).val()) === $(this).data('default')) {
                alert('default');
                return false;
            }
            IWannaChat.server.send($('#ideaBody').val());
            $.connection.hub.start();
        })

    });
});
```

Comment: Do you really want when BOTH the `if` statements are true? That can only happen when the default value is the empty string and the input is also empty.

Comment: I have two fields that are being checked, if they both validate and meet requirements, then the last conditional should be fired

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#sendMessage").click(function () {
    $('#ideaTitle,#ideaBody').each(function () {
        var $this = $(this),
            currValue = this.value,
            trimmedValue = $.trim(currValue),
            dataValue = $this.data('default');

        if (trimmedValue.length === 0 && (trimmedValue === dataValue)) {
            IWannaChat.server.send($('#ideaBody').val());
            $.connection.hub.start();
        } else if (trimmedValue.length === 0) {
            alert('empty');
            return false;
        } else if (trimmedValue === dataValue) {
            alert('default');
            return false;
        }
    })
});
```

You are using the same value multiple times in your code. Cache the values and use `&&` to club 2 statemenets

Comment: Thanks - can you show me where to place this in the context of my code. Really struggling

Answer (score 1):

You could return the conditions themselves:

```
$("#sendMessage").click(function () {
    $('#ideaTitle,#ideaBody').each(function () {
        var empty = $.trim($(this).val()).length === 0,
            def = $.trim($(this).val()) === $(this).data('default');
        if (empty) {
            alert('empty');
        }
        else if (def) {
            alert('default');
        }
        IWannaChat.server.send($('#ideaBody').val());
        $.connection.hub.start();
        return !empty && !def;
    });
});
```

Personally, I find this a little more readable.

Answer (score 1):

Use a variable to keep track of whether the earlier conditions were met.

```
$("#sendMessage").click(function () {
    $('#ideaTitle,#ideaBody').each(function () {
        var doit = true;
        if ($.trim($(this).val()).length === 0) {
            alert('empty');
            doit = true;
        }
        else if ($.trim($(this).val()) === $(this).data('default')) {
            alert('default');
            doit = true;
        }
        if (doit) {
            IWannaChat.server.send($('#ideaBody').val());
            $.connection.hub.start();
        }
    })

});
```